# Responsive Video Embed not working Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

Okay I've looked at all the the other questions similar to this but for some reason my responsive embed still isn't working.

Here's what I have in my html
    `

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/7645302?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0"  frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
```

`

Comment: How is it going to be responsive if you have set a specific width and height?

Comment: Also, why have you took a picture of your code instead of just pasting directly into your post?

Comment: Please post your code into your question rather thank linking to an image of the code.

Comment: Also post what you're doing to try to make it responsive that's failing. If this is just a general "how do I make a video responsive" question, rather than a specific issue with Bootstrap, then it seems like it might be a duplicate?

Comment: the width and height were included in the vimeo embed code and when i get rid of them the video gets tiny. Also I'm super new to asking questions and I don't know how to to post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the iframe width and height to 100%.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/237152408" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/973Lde7j/6/

Comment: thank you! that helped but it still doesn't fill the bootstrap col it's in.

Comment: I updated the code and fiddle with a container-fluid and col-lg-12. If you can't get this to work check out the [bootstrap grid system](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php)